# How do you write a Firebase Cloud Firestore rule to give access to specific collection documents where conditions are met on another collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My uidConnections collection is a linked list where the `uid` is the `request.auth.uid` and `connectedUid` == specialEvents.uid.

How do I write a Firebase Cloud Firestore rule where a user can only access specialEvents where the uidConnections.connectedUid == specialEvents.uid and uidConnections.uid == request.auth.uid?

[image]

**Where I'm currently at...**

```
function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}

match /specialEvents/{document=**} {
  allow read: if isSignedIn()
    && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/uidConnections).data.uid == request.auth.uid 
    && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/uidConnections).data.connectedUid == resource.data.uid;
}
```

I know that I could simply create an "allowed" list of uid's in specialEvents, but this would be limited to allowed document size. Hence the uidConnections linked list rather than an "allowed" list in specialEvents.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you would like, in your security rule to find a document in the `uidConnections` collection that verifies the different contraints.

With Firestore rules this is not possible, because, as explained the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?hl=en#access_other_documents) "the `get()` and `exists()` functions both expect fully specified document paths". In other words, you cannot execute a query in the rules, you need to know upfront the exact reference/path of the document you want to point to.

One solution would be to use the value of `connectedUid` as the ID of the doc. If you cannot do that you will need to find another approach. The one you mentioned in your question is a possible one. If you think there is a risk of reaching the size limit for one Firestore document, use a  (sub)collection.

Comment: Yep, got confused in docs on get(). You sparked a great though. In uidConnections the connection id could be {request.auth.uid}-{resource.data.uid}. Then I'd be able to use exists() or get() to create a firestore rule that would work to access specialEvents.

Comment: Glad I could help you. If my answer helped you please upvote it and please accept it if it answered your question.

Comment: I'm evaluating now and will def give you the credit, thanks for the good breakdown.

Comment: Hi @Zelf, did you have the time to evaluate the answer?

Comment: I ended up denormalizing data, because I could not get this to work without a bunch of hack code. I was never able to get this working and probably for good reason.